# Trouble building thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi due to 'Could not find bom-all.jar'

Tags: java, gradle, wildfly, thorntail

From the thorntail git-hub site:
https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi/

I tried building this example example project. However, I keep getting this error:

```
$ gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':thorntail-package'.
> Could not find bom-all.jar (io.thorntail:bom-all:2.3.0.Final).
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/home/wsi/.m2/repository/io/thorntail/bom-all/2.3.0.Final/bom-all-2.3.0.Final.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          10.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-43-generic amd64
```

Note using VERSION_THORNTAIL = 2.3.0.Final or 2.2.1.Final gives the same results

Any help would be appreciated, I'd like to use gradle to build my project, but if I can't get this to work, then I'll have to fall back to maven. I'm guessing there is a bug either in their build.gradle file or in the thorntail plugin and or the way the dependencies are configured. I guess if no one knows the answer I'll have to make a JIRA issue for this.

EDIT: I'm adding more information in response to comments below:
First with Java 10:

```
12:45 wsi@ubuntu ~/dev/workspace-thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi [master]: Up-to-date
$ java --version
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)

12:45 wsi@ubuntu ~/dev/workspace-thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi [master]: Up-to-date
$ ./gradlew clean build -DthorntailVersion=2.2.1.Final

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'example-gradle'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Multiple build operations failed.
         Could not initialize class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader
         Could not initialize class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader
         Could not initialize class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader
         Could not initialize class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

With Java 8 it builds, but the tests fail

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

12:47 wsi@ubuntu ~/dev/workspace-thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi [master]: Up-to-date
$ ./gradlew clean build -DthorntailVersion=2.2.1.Final

> Task :test

org.wildfly.swarm.examples.gradle.ArqWarDeploymentTest > classMethod FAILED
    org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException
        Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.NoResolvedResultException
            Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException
                Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException
                    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException
                        Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException
                            Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException
                                Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException

org.wildfly.swarm.examples.gradle.ArqContainerTest > classMethod FAILED
    org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException
        Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.NoResolvedResultException
            Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException
                Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException
                    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException
                        Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException
                            Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException
                                Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException

2 tests completed, 2 failed

> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/wsi/dev/workspace-thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 51s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

Edit 2: Adding more details from the 
file:///home/wsi/dev/workspace-thorntail-examples/gradle-examples/jaxrs-cdi/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
report

The stack trace is quite long, but here's the cause of the 2 failing tests:

1. org.wildfly.swarm.examples.gradle > ArqContainerTest

   ```
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://maven-server:8081/nexus/content/groups/releases/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.pom
   ```
2. org.wildfly.swarm.examples.gradle > ArqWarDeploymentTest

   ```
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://maven-server:8081/nexus/content/groups/releases/io/thorntail/msc/2.2.1.Final/msc-2.2.1.Final.pom
   ```

Comment: For all practical purposes, the Gradle plugin is maintained by a community member. If you can file a JIRA with steps to reproduce, I can assign it to him.

Comment: It's also highly possible that 2.3.0.Final wasn't available in Maven Central when you tried the build. Can you try again?

Comment: Hi Ken, I tried it both with 2.2.1.Final and 2.3.0.Final so its not that, I think. I can see both of their pom files in my repo. Looking at the pom files, they're both using packaging of 'pom' therefore, it looks like its a problem with the gradle plugin more than likely.

Comment: @Craig .. Looks 'bom-all' is not available for [2.3.0.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.thorntail/bom-all). Let me check with the Thorntail team. In the meantime, can you please confirm if the following command is working well for you?

`$> ./gradlew clean build -DthorntailVersion=2.2.1.Final`

Comment: @HarshaR I tried it using your suggestions and updated the question with the details.

Comment: I haven't tested with Java 10, so cannot comment on that piece right now. With respect to JDK 8, I have only tested it with Oracle Java .. I am wondering if you have security constraint configured for accessing the repository in your pom.xml file. I am assuming that you might have a mirror pointing to an enterprise repository. Can you confirm if your current `.m2/settings.xml` file has an authorization constraint?

Comment: @HarshaR The settings are fine. I'm able to resolve the dependency and build the project with Java 8 (not with Java 10). However, now I'm seeing test failures when I perform a gradle build with Java 8.

Comment: @Craig .. Good to hear about the progress. Can you share a sample exception for the failure? You can find them in the generated test report. You might want to look at the STD_OUT & STD_ERR logs to get the root cause.

Comment: @HarshaR OK, I've updated the question again to include the cause of the test failures. As you can see 2 of the dependencies fail to be resolved or my maven-server doesn't authorize them to be downloaded. Strange that it was able to download dependencies when building, but not while testing. Should I modify the build.gradle file to include an external maven repo?

Comment: @Craig ... As you have rightly identified, if you have a custom repository in place, then you might need to add an external repository before the custom repo. I am assuming that `maven-server:8081` is a custom container which is facing issues when proxying content from the remote site. Can you please let us know if that is the root cause of the problem?